# Match the values of a row in table with values in a column in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this 2 tables:

```
+---------------+--------+
|      id1      |  name  |
+---------------+--------+
| 1             | test   |
| 2             | teest  |
| 3             | teeest |
+---------------+--------+

+-----+------------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id2 |    date    | morning | afternoon | evening | 
+-----+------------+---------+-----------+---------+
|   1 | 2017-12-14 |     1   |      2    |     1   |
|   2 | 2017-12-15 |     2   |      1    |     3   |
+-----+------------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

All I want to do is to `echo`, in a php file, the values of the second table but instead of numbers I want to echo the names of the first table in their place.

Can someone teach me how to take this result?

Edit: When i use this code:

```
<?php
     $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table2");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<center>" . $row['date'] . " " .$row['morning']. " " .$row['afternoon']. " " .$row['evening']. "</center>";
     }
?>
```

i have the result

```
2017-12-14 1 2 1
2017-12-15 2 1 3
```

and i want this instead:

```
2017-12-14 test teest test
2017-12-15 teest test teeest
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please past here the CREATE TABLE statements of both tables to check if they are correct.

Comment: Those tables are just examples. I just added some code and more details of what i want to achive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **`JOIN`**.

**Query**

```
 select 
  `t2`.`id2`,
  `t2`.`date`,
  `ta1`.`name` as `morning`,
  `ta2`.`name` as `afternoon`,
  `ta3`.`name` as `evening`
from `table2` as `t2`
join `table1` as `ta1`
on `ta1`.`id1` = `t2`.`morning`
join `table1` as `ta2`
on `ta2`.`id1` = `t2`.`afternoon`
join `table1` as `ta3`
on `ta3`.`id1` = `t2`.`evening`;
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2e9fd/1)**

Comment: What does ta1,ta2,ta3 stands for?

Comment: @StavrosS : It's just table **`alias`**

Comment: Alias yes, but i don't get what's exactly for the ta1 etc. t2 its the second table as i see. ta1=ta2=ta3= first table? (i am sorry for asking the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Select the values from the first table into an array and when presenting the second table, use the values of the second table as keys.

Sample:

```
$names = [1 => 'test', 2 => 'teest', 3 => 'teeest'];

echo $names[$secondrow["morning"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...

The best is to have those table with `INNODB` engine with relation between tables, ie `foreign key` defined between second table to the first table.

Then you will run SQL query to database using the relation you will receive data from both tables and in the `SELECT` part of the query you define what columns to be shown.

```
SELECT atable.name, btable.* 
FROM btable
JOIN atable ON btable.name_id = atable.id;
```

Here is my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e851e0/3